# mysqli Results Coming Back Different

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote a PHP function using mysqli and the results I get back are different than what is store inside the MySQL database. I tried the MySQL commands within phpMyAdmin and everything came back as I expected.

```
Users Table
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Id [int(11)]|Username [varchar(16)]|Status [enum('Active', 'Inactive')]
---------------------------------------------------------------------
          1 |                  ABC |         Active
          2 |                  DEF |         Active


PMK Table
------------------------------
Id [int(11)]|Camel [tinyint(1)]
------------------------------
          1 |        1
          2 |        0


function getFeature($script, $username, $feature)
{
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Username = ? AND Status = 'Active'");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $id = $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->free_result();

    if(isset($id) && !empty($id))
    {
        switch($script)
        {
            case "PMK":
                switch($feature)
                {
                    case "Camel":
                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Select Camel FROM PMK WHERE Id = $id");
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->bind_result($access);
                        $access = $stmt->fetch();
                        $stmt->free_result();
                        printf("%s:%s:%s:%s", $script, $feature, $username, $access);
                        break;
                    default:
                        echo "[ERROR]";
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                echo "[ERROR]";
                break;
        }

    } else {
        echo "[ERROR]";
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Did I do something wrong in my function that would cause my results to be different?

Comment: You're using prepared statements, which is the right way to do it, but what is `$id` doing in your second one? That's a giant [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Try to be disciplined about avoiding this.

Comment: @tadman $id is the results from a previous prepared statment. Someone has editted my post and now it looks all messed up.

Comment: And you are **sure** `$id` is an integer? Better be safe then sorry.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I would assume so, since they are int(11) in the database. Not sure if it comes out differently.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it is in the database. What matters is that `$id` is showing up in your query string without any sort of [escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: @tadman I am not entirely sure what $id shows up as from my query string. I am not very familiar with PHP/MySQL and this is my attempt at it. The problem starts at the first query string; I get back "1" no matter which username (ABC and DEF) I use.

Comment: What I'm saying is simple: Avoid using string interpolation when composing queries. Do not put things like `$id` directly in your query string. Your first `prepare` call uses placeholders `?` correctly, the second one has a SQL injection hole because you're not using them.

Comment: $id comes directly from the first prepared; is SQLI still possible even in that case? If so, can you explain how it would happen? Aside from the SQLI issue, any idea what is causing the $id to always come back as 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. The issue was due to variable conflicting with each other. I used $id for both binding and storing the fetch when I wasn't supposed to; changing the variable name solved the issue.

So glad you guys were so helpful :D